# Can you instantiate another `BrowserRouter` inside a `BrowserRouter` based App?

Tags: react-router-dom, sweetalert2, sweetalert2-react-content

Background: I am trying to use [sweetalert2-react-content](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content) to let me put a react `<Link>` inside a [Sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) `footer`.

Generally speaking `sweetalert2-react-content` is supposed to let you place react JSX into its fields, like this:

```
MySwal.fire({
      text: "Fire fire",
      footer: <div>Call the firebrigade</div>
});
```

... and indeed that sort of thing does work.

However, putting a `<Link>` there does not work: it renders empty.

In [this issue resolution message](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content/issues/194#issuecomment-1122038283) the the advice is "wrap your element in `BrowserRouter` like this:

```
MySwal.fire({
  html: (
    <BrowserRouter>
      ...
    </BrowserRouter>
  ),
})
```

Is this "legitimate"?   What does it "mean" to have a `BrowserRouter` inside an app that is routed using `BrowserRouter` already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is an invariant violation to nest a router within another router. I think your situation is not a case of invalid nesting, but more to do with ***where*** `sweetalert` is rendering the React JSX. From what I recall of `sweetalert` it renders content outside the ReactTree.

You can certainly render more than one router, so long as they are not nested, but then the issue is that you've separate routing contexts that each individually handle routing/navigation, and navigating within one routing context doesn't update the others.

I suspect you could use a single custom `history` reference and pass these to the routers you need, so they all reference the same history context internally.

`react-router-dom@6` exports a [`HistoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/history-router) for this purpose.

Example:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory({ window });

export default history;
```

...

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../path/to/history";

ReactDOM.render(
  <HistoryRouter history={history}>
    {/* The rest of your app goes here */}
  </HistoryRouter>,
  root
);
```

...

```
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../path/to/history";

MySwal.fire({
  html: (
    <HistoryRouter history={history}>
      ...
    </HistoryRouter>
  ),
})
```

Note about `unstable_HistoryRouter`:

> This API is currently prefixed as `unstable_` because you may
> unintentionally add two versions of the `history` library to your app,
> the one you have added to your package.json and whatever version React
> Router uses internally. If it is allowed by your tooling, it's
> recommended to not add history as a direct dependency and instead rely
> on the nested dependency from the react-router package. Once we have a
> mechanism to detect mis-matched versions, this API will remove its
> `unstable_` prefix.

Comment: Thanks, awesome.   Would you be kind enough to briefly elaborate on this: "but then the issue is that you've separate routing contexts that each individually handle routing/navigation, and navigating within one routing context doesn't update the others."

Comment: @GreenAsJade Each router component maintains its own routing context value that it is providing to the various links, routes, etc components being rendered *under* it in *its* React subtree. If you have multiple routers, they don't "cross communicate", so any actions done in one routing context aren't shared to other routing contexts. They operate independently. For example, if you place your links within a router in a nav component, and the app's routes within a different router, then clicking the links will correctly update the URL in the address bar, but the matched route won't update.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is wrong and will usually throw an error.
What you would like to do is to render it like this:

```
 <UNSAFE_LocationContext.Provider value={null as any}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      ...
    </BrowserRouter>
 </UNSAFE_LocationContext.Provider>
```

Comment: It's reassuring to hear that my instincts are correct in thinking it wrong, but UNSAFE things don't sound like an attractive option either?

Comment: Noteworthy react-router-dom ticket, I guess: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8867